# How to open multiple instances of the same fragment but with different data, one after the other?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-fragmentactivity

I made several api calls from a model class of an `Activity` and upon receiving responses from each of them, I need to feed the data to a `Fragment` one after the other by invoking multiple instances of the same fragment.

Ideally, the next fragment will only be fed with data after the previous `Fragment` has exited (by response from a listener).

I have looked everywhere and couldn't find a solution to this problem. I have tried using AsyncTask with a CountDownLatch to block the next api response before getting an action response from the initial `Fragment` but after it only invoked one `Fragment` (I know how many fragments I should be creating) and back to normal `Activity` view.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this problem?

Comment: What seems to be the problem ? Are you not able to create multiple instances of a Fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways for this

1. Create a constructor to the fragment where you pass the data when you create instances.

mFragment1 = new xFragment(dataA);
mFragment2 = new xFragment(dataB)

2. To use Interface and Implementation to pass data from Activity to. Check the link below

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html